# gdlib-config Ubuntu 16.04 / Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

I'm on a W10 Host using VirtualBox. I had set up two virtual environments :  Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm trying to install the GD perl module. For this I need the gdlib-config file.

I'm able to get it with Ubuntu 16.04 using the following :

```
$whereis gdlib-config
gdlib-config:
$sudo apt-get install libgd-dev
$whereis gdlib-config
gdlib-config: /usr/bin/gdlib-config /usr/share/man/man1/gdlib-config.1.gz
```

Same command lines under Ubuntu 18.04 :

```
$whereis gdlib-config
gdlib-config:
$sudo apt-get install libgd-dev
$whereis gdlib-config
gdlib-config:
```

Both libgd-dev installations ends successfully

Where can I get the gdlib-config for Ubuntu 18.04 ? Why did they remove gdlib-config file from the libgd-dev library ?

Thanks